# Export animated .egg

Tags: export

I'm making a game using Panda3D, and I need to use animated models. I can't figure out how to export an animated `.egg` file. Can someone help? (I'm using Blender 2.79)

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in exporter for the `.egg` format, you need to install a third-party add-on. It seems that for 2.5x - 2.7x you can use [YABEE](https://github.com/09th/YABEE) which is recommended in the [Panda3D manual](https://www.panda3d.org/manual/?title=Converting_from_Blender). For newer versions of Blender it seems that glTF is another option, although it seems that a plug-in for Panda3D's is needed to import the format according to this [post on Panda3D's discourse](https://discourse.panda3d.org/t/yabee-and-blender-2-8/24996/16).

Comment: I have already installed YABEE, but I can't figure out how to export the animation.

Comment: @iDoProgramming Have you read the *How to* that comes with the add-on? (https://github.com/09th/YABEE/blob/master/YABEE_HowTo.pdf)